# $\sigma_{min}(A+B)\ge \sigma_{min}(A)+\sigma_{min}(B)$ ? (for singular values)

Tags: linear-algebra

minimum singular value is defined as for matrix A:

$\sigma_{min}(A)=min_{\lVert x\rVert_2=1} \lVert Ax\rVert_2$

How to prove:

$\sigma_{min}(A+B)\ge \sigma_{min}(A)+\sigma_{min}(B)$

Comment: It is not true for scalars. $|1-1|=0$, $|1|+|-1| = 2$.

Comment: But what happens if $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative?

Comment: @Surb With $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$, $\sigma_{\min}(A+B)=0\not\geq\sigma_{\min}(A)+\sigma_{\min}(B)=2$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks for this answer :)

Comment: This suggests another interesting question: what are conditions that guarantee the inequality above to be true? Maybe if we consider only non-zero singular values (and the minimum between them) it could work... Because all of the counterexamples proposed here rely on this $0$...

Comment: No, you can take a small perturbation so $0$ is not a singular value of $A+B$ and it'll still be false.

Answer (score 2):

Not true.  Try $A = I$, $B = -I$.

EDIT: If $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite (hermitian, or real symmetric) matrices, then
the inequality is true.